# Uninstalling Desktop sharing programs

Tags: security, remote, installed-programs

Sine I want the most security as possible, I'm removing some programs that could give the access to remote desktop. In this case, I removed the Remmina Desktop Client (I think, if it comes with Ubuntu).

So, my question is if there's any problem by removing this program (I never use remote desktop), and also, does removing them improve my security?

Thabk you guys for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, my question is if there's any problem by removing this program (I never use remote desktop),

No.

> And also, does removing them improve my security?

No. Ubuntu is shipped as secure as possible. If Remmina would be a security problem by just being installed it would have been removed from our installation. And any Linux system for that matter. Security is not taken lightly in Linux installations.

In general: you need to have vulnerable services exposed to the internet for someone to enter your systen. So for someone to abuse Remmina to access your system it 1st needs to be active (it is not when not running).

---

If you are concerned about this I would approach this from another point of view: your 1st line of defense is your router. Check that 1st for possible security holes. Like: is there any forwarding that does not need to be there. Update your router software (I installed [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) on mine). Enable logging on the router and if possible enable alert/mail messages.

And on your Ubuntu system check for running services and disable them if you do not need them. In a default Ubuntu there are not a lot of services to disable though.

---

And of course it is always good to think about the value of your system to other people. If you have a normal desktop system it should not be of interest unless you pissed someone off really bad and they want to target you specifically. If you have a system with several webshops running on it security needs to be one of the main priorities. Those might be targetted by automated scripts.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm a bit scared, because in AskUbuntu, there are some people who got hacked, and it makes me scared. Now, about your tips: 1 - Right now I'm using the internet from the college, so I really can't do anything now. But when I go to home, I'm thinking about updating my router software to the program you gave as example (at home, I have a really old router). 2 - I haven't installed many things here, so I don't think there's anything wrong, but I will check it. 3 - Yeah, I only have a normal desktop, and I didn't pissed off anyone to be a target.